How is it possible to start more threads than my machine's logical cores?
I have created below program to understand the threads.
Below program creates 1000 threads and created the loop to run for very very long.
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    Console.WriteLine("Creating Thread " + j);   
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running thread " + j);
        for(var k = 0; k < 1000000000000000000; k++) { }
        Console.WriteLine("Completing thread " + j);
    }).Start();
}

Console.ReadLine();

It is showing me below results and keep growing. How that is possible when my machine has only 8 logical cores, and those are already in loop?
Creating Thread 0
Creating Thread 1
Creating Thread 2
Running thread 1
Running thread 0
Creating Thread 3
Creating Thread 4
Running thread 2
Creating Thread 5
Running thread 3
Creating Thread 6
Running thread 4
Running thread 5
Creating Thread 7
Creating Thread 8
Running thread 6
Creating Thread 9
Running thread 8
Running thread 7
Creating Thread 10
Running thread 9
Creating Thread 11
Running thread 10
Running thread 11
Creating Thread 12
Creating Thread 13
Running thread 12
Creating Thread 14
Running thread 13
Creating Thread 15
Running thread 14
Creating Thread 16
Running thread 15
Creating Thread 17
Running thread 16
Creating Thread 18
Running thread 17
Creating Thread 19
Running thread 18
Creating Thread 20
Running thread 19
Creating Thread 21
Running thread 20
Creating Thread 22


Most likely you have 8 cores and X threads, so the operating system will destribute the threads accross the cores you have.

A core can run multiple threads. It's called context switching. Windows itself uses over 10K threads, which you can see easily in Task Manager.

The era of general purpose programs being handed a whole physical resource like a processor core or block of memory ended a long time ago. You need to update your conceptual model of how modern operating systems work.

Do keep in mind that starting a thread creates a stack that uses at least 1MB of RAM. 1_000 threads is 1GB of RAM. It's not ideal for performance.

FYI: Threads were invented years before multi-CPU computers escaped from the lab and became a commercial reality. Threading is a model of concurrency. That is, the ability of a program to have multiple, independent tasks that all are "in progress" at the same time. Concurrency is useful even when you have only one CPU available to perforrm the tasks. In the human world we call it "multi-tasking:" E.g., a single person can divide their attention between eating their lunch and writing an essay and waiting for their stock broker to return a phone call, all "at the same time."

As Ken said, this is related with how windows works. A core could handle many threads and it doesn't one by one run the thread, the system can perform context switching to give the appearance that more threads are running. Each core can switch between multiple threads rapidly.
This is the reason why you see it start so many threads.
More details about how context switching, you could refer to this article.

"this is related with how windows works." Not just Windows, this works the same on other mainstream OSes.
